# How do big companies ensure that other people don't register a new top level domain with their name?

Tags: dns-domain

For example today there are ".codes", ".farm" and ".vaijes" newly available.
How do big companies like google, facebook, twitter, .. keep sure that they are the first who register their name on the new domain? Is there any contract they have with the domain registrar?

Comment: Google employs thousands of people sitting in front of computers whose sole job is snatching up domain names when they become available.

Comment: @TerryChia, I would like to see the facts for that assumption...

Comment: @norbertVC, this question probably doesnt belong on the security side of StackExchange...

Answer (score 2):

The "big companies" would work with the [Trademark Clearinghouse](http://www.trademark-clearinghouse.com/content/what-clearinghouse) which exists for exactly this purpose. It gives trademark owners earlier ("sunrise") access to new domains and alerts them when someone tries to register a domain matching their trademark. See also the [ICANN page on this topic](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/about/trademark-clearinghouse).

Answer (score 1):

They also have the resources to sue the pants off anyone who happens to register one.

Take a look at bitsquatting and typosquatting, those are about as close as people are likely to get.

Comment: I once registered a domain name NFLpaintball.com and got a takedown notice from the NFL even though the domain name meant North Florida, so I can confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches which they usually follow.

### Proactive Approach

They register the domain themselves.

### Reactive Approach

They have teams which routinely monitor for registration on domains sounding similar to their watchlist. Once such a domain pops up, they work on taking down the domain citing anti-cybersquatting and filing a domain name dispute to agencies such as WIPO.

Answer (score 0):

New domain spaces often have a pre register period where you can reserve a domain. If they get multiple requests for one domain they can check how has rights for this domain.

Otherwise big companies will sue you and give you some money to go away.

Answer (score 0):

When a company wants a domain name which is similar to one of their trademarks, they can sue for the domain. In such a dispute over a domain name, companies with a trademark usually get preference over private people who do not. An example case was when [Microsoft sued for MikeRoweSoft.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_vs._MikeRoweSoft).

In that case it was about a domain name just phonetically similar to their trademark.  Also, the owner of that domain was not just a squatter but had legitimate use for the domain.

Result: MS got the domain through a settlement. But reading between the lines of the settlement definitely shows that the settlement was a PR decision, not a legal one. When they wouldn't have been afraid of media backlash, Microsoft would have won.